# Dreamweaver | dynamically-related files | shows up all files except .php files

Tags: dreamweaver

When I tried to edit a WordPress site, I:

- set up a local testserver (MAMP)
- created a "new site" in DW
- opened up the *index.php* of the WP root folder
- initiated the procedure to discover dynamically-related files

Up to this point, everything worked fine: The website shows up in DW's live preview and in a web browser perfectly. DW resolved all dynamically related files to the *index.php* by its build-in feature as expected (CSS, JS, SVG, XML, PHP) and they showed up in the top bar of DW correctly.

My problem: 
Except the *xmlrpc.php* file, **no PHP files are shown** in the *Related Files* list (no errors showing up).

This issue is replicable on different WP sites (whether an existing one or a fresh new one).
I've already deleted Dreamweaver and reinstalled it with no success. I've also set  WP's permalinks to default with no success.

How can I solve this?

[Screenshot | Annotated issues: a new installed WordPress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo6Mf.jpg)
[Screenshot | Annotated issues: an existing WordPress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84dY2.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked to see if the missing files actually exist in the project/WP folder

Comment: As you can see in the right area of both screenshots: Yes, they exist. Without them, the pages would not be rendered.